# Memory leak in Program to Rotate an image

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am new to c++ programming, I have written a program to rotate an image. The input for image is in ppm format. I am having a memory leak in my main function or the rotate function with below signature:

```
     <vector> rotate(picture);
```

I have tried to debug a lot using valgrind but was unable to catch the issue, here is the simplified, executable version of the code:       http://ideone.com/vHjv

could anyone please help me out with this, thank you

**Note**: The code may seem long, the leak is at the end of the rotate() function or main(). I don't know what is causing the leak.

Comment: hi readers, i am just not asking this question because I am lazy to debug or something like that, I have tried a lot but i was unable to find the issue. Hope you understand, thanks

Comment: Not sure why you have `myMemCpy( ppm.pixels, newPixel, ppm.size * sizeof (Pixel) );` in your rotate function when you already acquire the values of ppm.pixels to newPixel. This might be causing your memory leak as you allocate memory by `char *temp = new char[n]` on the heap.

Comment: @macroland I have the myMemCpy function because i want to copy newPixel to ppm.pixels.because newPixel is a local variable and i will get rid of it

Comment: If you are planning to rotate the `PpmArray& ppm`, which you passed by reference, why dont you directly access to ppm.pixels array with a loop within `rotate` function and copy newpixel values to it. I guess again the `memcpy` is causing the memory leak.

Comment: You can further reduce your code to a minimal example. Post the minimal example as part of your example instead of behind a link.

Comment: Whoops, I meant as part of your *question*.

Comment: Just use smart pointers and `std::vector` instead of `new` and `delete` so you never have to worry about memory leaks anymore. :)

Answer (score 1):

In the function `myMemCpy` you forgot to deallocate `temp`. There is a function for copying an array in the standard library. It's named quite aptly: `std::copy`. I suggest that you use it instead of your leaky version. To further reduce your risk of leaks, use `std::vector` instead of pointers to raw arrays.

Comment: using copy is giving me errors, how would you use it?

Comment: @Jimmy what did you try?

Comment: copy (start,end,image); ?

Comment: @Jimmy yes, that's how you call it. I recommend that you take a look at the error message.

Comment: where are the destination and source parameters? ; dest: image is there but where is source?

Comment: @Jimmy that would be the array you're copying from.

Comment: I used copy still getting an error, could you please look at the edited code in link. but i think this error is a more straight forward one..

Comment: @Could you please take a look at the error message. It usually tells you what's wrong.

Comment: "incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed."

Comment: @Jimmy You never update `pBegin` to point to the new `image` after you've deleted it and reallocated. You could get rid of most of this bughunting by using `std::vector`.

Comment: How can I update begin correctly, I tried updating it like: pBegin = pEnd;
                 pEnd = image + capacity;

Comment: And also i have allocated newImage but haven't deleted it anywhere, is that a mistake? if yes at which point shall i delete?

Comment: At that point `pEnd` also points to the old array (or rather, one past it). That assignment is nonsensical. You can get the pointer to the first element of the new array like this: `pBegin = image`. But that variable is quite useless since you could pass `image` to `copy` as it is.

Comment: Yes, you must delete everything that you've allocated. If you don't do that, then you leak the memory. You should delete it when you no longer use it.